# mean-deviation form, why orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, projective-geometry, least-squares, means

This is from my textbook
[image]

Why the column of the new design matrix are orthogonal?
for example, let say

$A=\begin{pmatrix}
 1&  1& 4\\ 
 1&  2& 0\\ 
 1&  3& 2
\end{pmatrix}$

how to caclulate the mean-deviation form of matrix A?

Answer (score 0):

Without the details of how the matrix $\mathbf{A}$ was formed, we are restricted to guessing.

Suppose $\mathbf{A}$ is a collection of column vectors
$$
\mathbf{A} =
\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
  x_{1} & x_{2} & x_{3}
\end{array} \right]
$$
The transformation would be
$$
  \tilde{x}_{k} = x_{k} - \bar{x}.
$$
The transformed matrix is
$$
\tilde{\mathbf{A}} =
\left[
\begin{array}{crr}
 0 & -1 & 2 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & -2 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
Quick check: the columns all have sum $0$.